# Cannot transfer rented movie from iPod to computer?

Tags: itunes-store

I rented a movie on my iPod touch 5th gen and want to sync it to my computer so I can watch it there. It won't transfer however. What do I do? Do I have to rent it again on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

[Per Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201611), if you rent a movie on an iOS device or AppleTV, you cannot move it to another device or computer.

(The reverse, however, is possible - you can rent on a computer then transfer to an iOS device.)